# deploymentRes for a pvc using the dynamic-create

Tags: go, kubernetes, yaml, client-go

I'm trying to use the client-go to create pods and other resources on my cluster.

From what I understand the best way to create stuff on your cluster using client-go is to use the dynamic-create version (in the examples there is a dynamic-create-update-delete example). Because I can just take my yaml and make it into unstructured.Unstructured and then create the resource.

This is working fine for me while creating pods using `kind: Deployment` but when I try to create a pod with the `kind: PersistentVolumeClaim` I get an error:

> panic: PersistentVolumeClaim in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: converting (v1.PersistentVolumeClaim).v1.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec to (apps.Deployment).apps.DeploymentSpec: Replicas not present in src

If I understand the error correctly this happen because I declare my deploymentRes with the `resource: "deployments"`

```
deploymentRes := schema.GroupVersionResource{Group: "apps", Version: "v1", Resource: "deployments"}
```

And then create with the:

```
client.Resource(deploymentRes).Namespace(namespace).Create(context.TODO(), deployment, metav1.CreateOptions{})
```

The problem here is that I can't find what to put instead of `Resource: "deployments"` when I want to create a pvc. I have tried to put in `persistentvolumeclaim` but just get the err:

> "panic: the server could not find the requested resource"

Please if you know anything that could help, or put me in the right direction would be super helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The problem here is that I can't find what to put instead of Resource: "deployments" when I want to create a pvc

Your assumptions are correct. You missed only two points:

- The `Group` argument should be `""` (empty string)
- The `Resource` argument should be `"persistentvolumeclaims"` (in the plural form)

```
pvcRes := schema.GroupVersionResource{Group: "", Version: "v1", Resource: "persistentvolumeclaims"}
```